# Programming Puzzle - Fibonacci

Tags: c, algorithm

There was some prior confusion over this question. Previously, the original poster and those that responded thought this was a broken function to calculate the nth Fibonacci number, but in fact it's a working function to calculate the nth prime Fibonacci number as a programming puzzle from codegolf at Stack Exchange.

```
f(n){int i=1,j=0,k;for(;n;n-=k==i)for(j=i-j,i+=j,k=2;i%k&&k++<i;);return i;}
```

It's the C 76 character example from

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/find-the-nth-fibonnaci-prime-in-the-shortest-code

For 32 bit signed integers, the range for n is 1 to 10. The first 10 prime Fibonacci numbers are: 2, 3, 5, 13, 89, 233, 1597, 28657, 514229, 433494437 .

The question is how does this function work?

The original source for this at codegolf doesn't include an explanation. This probably belongs at codegolf, but the previous question was asked here at SO, and I'm hoping the poster of the previous question will see this and get his/her question answered.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @rcgldr What "previous question"? And that still doesn't explain what *your* question is.

Comment: It's still a mess. "There was some confusion over this question" - there still is, especially because it starts with a statement like that without any context. "Previously it was thought" - by whom? When? "the previous question was asked here at SO" - what previous question are you talking about?

Comment: The OP of the other question was @programmerfolk. So now that s/he has been messaged, you may wish to self answer. I still say that using a debugger, or adding a few printfs would be the best way to understand what the function is doing.

Comment: Yup, normally you could just leave a comment on another question or answer by @programmerfolk, but since there are none, you're kind of stuck. So the best thing is to go ahead and post your answer, and hope s/he sees it.

Comment: @user3386109 - Now that the purpose of the function is understood (calculate nth prime Fibonacci number), and although I could answer this, I'm wanting to give programmerfolk a chance to figure this out on his/her own. If there's no answer in a few days, I can just delete the question assuming that's the point of the downvotes, or it may get closed by close votes

Comment: Sounds good, we'll see what happens...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's indent it first:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int i = 1, j = 0, k;
    for (; n; n -= k == i)
        for (j = i - j, i += j, k = 2; i % k && k++ < i;) ;
    return i;
}
```

`n` is non-zero for reasonable inputs, so the first loop will execute. Note that `k == i` is not evaluated yet, because the body of the first `for` has to execute first, so it doesn't matter that `k` is not initialized.

For a more mathematical demonstration of this, note that `j = f(0) = 0` and `i = f(2) = 1` are the first and third Fibonacci numbers. Starting with `n = 2`, `j = f(n-2) = 0`, `i = f(n) = 1`, to advance j and i, we have:

```
j = i - j = f(n) - f(n-2) = f(n-1)
i = i + j = f(n) + f(n-1) = f(n+1)
n = n + 1
```

For each outer loop, `i` and `j` are advanced to the next Fibonacci numbers in the inner loop's initialization.

```
j =  1 == f(1), i =  2 == f(3)
j =  1 == f(2), i =  3 == f(4)
j =  2 == f(3), i =  5 == f(5)
j =  3 == f(4), i =  8 == f(6)
j =  5 == f(5), i = 13 == f(7)
```

Which confirms our pattern: we can see from the first few iterations that `i` is two steps ahead of `j`.

```
i % k && k++ < i
```

This is just a primality test: it stops when `k` is equal to `i` (this happens if `i` is prime - also `k++ < i` will technically never fail to be true, because the first condition will evaluate to false first, but it has a useful side effect) or when `k` is a proper divisor of `i` (so `i` is not prime). It's not the most efficient thing, but it works.

Putting `k++` in the conditional part of the `for` loop has the effect of incrementing it correctly and saving a few more characters (well, just one I think).

```
n -= k == i
```

If `i` wasn't prime, this doesn't change `n`, so the next Fibonacci number will be checked (since `i` iterates over the Fibonacci sequence). If `i` was prime, then it decrements `n`, which counts down the number of prime Fibonacci numbers we've found, and the next prime will be checked anyway. When it reaches `0`, we'll have found the `n`th.

> The question is how does this function work?

It works by computing the Fibonacci numbers sequentially and testing each one for primality, until it has found `n` such primes.

There is little fancy once you clean the code up a little. Mostly just the brute force algorithm a lot of people would write, although a bit less efficient due to the primality check and harder to read due to wanting to save as many characters as possible.

The part that stands out the most is the computation of `i` and `j`, which puts `i` two steps ahead of `j`. This trick probably also has the effect of saving the most characters.

Comment: Having i two steps ahead of j is different than the typical methods.

Comment: @rcgldr that's true, I added a bit to highlight that.